# Store data available to multiple computers to be changed and rewritten

Tags: c#, serialization

I am trying to write a program that generates a specific serial number but it will be able to be accessed by multiple computers in different locations. 
The serial number will look something like this:

```
(2 letters)AA(month)02(year)16(four numbers)0000
Full thing: AA02160000
```

The last 4 digits will increment by one every time the user clicks a button. 
I need to be able to get that serial number from multiple computers in different locations not on the same network and edit it and rewrite it. I can't have any sort of overlap being a serial number and unique to a specific item. I also can't use a guid for the number otherwise it would be much easier.

What is the best way to do this in C#?

I have considered making a server for it but I was running into problems when trying to create directories to pull the number from because of the drive letter.

Can I access a website that is hosted on a computer in one location and have it grab that serial number and increment it and then place the new value on the website?

A bit of help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Web service?  Database?

Comment: I was considering a database but how would every computer be able to access that database if they are in local storage?

Comment: I think that you can use a DB with an API (with methods get and increase). But I don't know if the computers can connect to internet or if they are in the same local network.

Comment: Well the bad way would be to allow every computer to connect to the database server. The good way would be to create a Web Service which is called by the program running on all the computers (or even a single web application page where you pass something as querystring) and have that write to the database or other kind of local (for the server) storage.

Comment: I think most databases in C# are a local database. I need it to be accessible from multiple locations. A web service might work. I don't know what to you use though.

Comment: add it as a resource string or a value that's stored in the setting.Settings within your application.. does the serial number ever change..? store this in a DataBase if you are wanting to use an Incremented approach

Comment: @Creplav `I think most databases in C# are local..?` not true

Comment: @Creplav No, many databases are server-based and are designed to be access by multiple computers across a network.

Answer (score 1):

1. You could use the Google Docs (or SpreadSheets) and its api.
   https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet

But you will need access to Internet on all the computers

2. Another way is to use UNC shared location in your local network for the file.
3. Also you could create WCF service to update it and write/read the SN to a file (no need to set up db for it)